# How to restart polkitd?

Tags: opensuse, d-bus, freedesktop

My desktop PC is also used as a NIS/NFS server for a small workgroup. It runs for months without reboot.

Recently I observed that when I log into a desktop session the computer becomes less responsive for several minutes. A `polkitd` process in a `D` state generates a lot of disk I/O activity. Its VmSize is over 600MB and its VmRSS is over 400MB.

The machine is still on OpenSUSE 11.3 with polkit 0.96. I plan to upgrade in the summer.

There are several reports of memory leaks in polkitd that were fixed in 0.98 ([freedesktop.org](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29069), [opensuse.org](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638784)). While upgrading will probably solve the problem it would take about a day and I am looking for a quick fix.

There is no polkitd script in /etc/init.d and the parent for the polkitd process is `init` itself.

```
    PID  PPID USER     CMD
      ....
  22362     1 root     /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd
```

**Question:** How do I restart polkitd without rebooting the system? Can I do it from within a desktop session or should I log off the desktop session and log on to the text console?

Answer (score 4):

The man page for polkitd says:

> ... Users or administrators should never need to start this daemon as it
>   will be automatically started by dbus-daemon(1) ...

Therefore polkitd will be restarted when `dbus` service is restarted. Since this service interacts with the desktop manager it is safer to log out of the desktop session, stop `xdm` service, restart `dbus` and start `xdm` again.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that even on a headless (text-mode only) OpenSuSE you can do `rcdbus restart`. Needed this when `zypper ps` indicated that `polkitd` was using a deleted file and needed to be restarted after a `zypper dup` (I run Tumbleweed on some systems) or `zypper up` (on regular releases).

Answer (score 3):

You should run:

```
invoke-rc.d dbus restart
```

as root.

Comment: Isn't this a subset of the answer offered by Dmitri Chubarov?

Answer (score 2):

When using systemd, restarting polkit is as easy as: `sudo systemctl restart polkitd.service`

Comment: ubuntu server 18.04.6 LTS - no polkitd, had to do `sudo systemctl restart polkit`

Answer (score 1):

I have been encountering the *polkitd* memory leak in my Ubuntu 10.04 desktop.

I use the command 
`ps -ef | grep polkitd` to find the process ID and then use `kill -9 procid`

The polkitd process will be killed but it will be started again by the system. And the polkitd process will once again start leaking memory.

Comment: On Linux you could also use `pgrep` to get the process ID as in `pgrep polkitd`. And also `pkill` to kill the process with the name that matches a given pattern.

Comment: Does SIGTERM really not work? SIGKILL is a last resort, not a first...

Answer (score 0):

Run this in a terminal:

```
killall -HUP polkitd
```